# @ContainedIn isn't work in Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

There are two entities, **Atendimento** and **CadastroFornecedor**.

There is an index: Atendimento.

I need the **Atendimento** index to be updated when **CadastroFornecedor** is saved.

Then I use @IndexedEmbedded on "private CadastroFornecedor fornecedor" field, and use @ContainedIn on "private List atendimentos", to create the "two-way databind".

But when the CadastroFornecedor is updated, the index of Atendimento isn't updated.

```
@Indexed
@org.hibernate.envers.Audited
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATDT")
public class Atendimento extends Entidade<AtendimentoPK> {

    private static final long         serialVersionUID = 74150159447253081L;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @FieldBridge(impl = ChavePrimariaAtendimentoBridge.class)
    @EmbeddedId
    private AtendimentoPK             chavePrimaria;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_CAD_FRNC", referencedColumnName = "CD_CAD_FRNC")
    private CadastroFornecedor        fornecedor;

    //more code here...
}


@org.hibernate.envers.Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAD_FRNC")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CD_CAD_FRNC")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class CadastroFornecedor extends Cadastro {

    private static final long                serialVersionUID = 6508970622894252312L;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name = "TX_URL_SITE_FRNC", length = 150, nullable = true)
    private String                           urlSite;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @DateBridge(encoding = EncodingType.STRING, resolution = Resolution.MILLISECOND)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "TS_INCL_FRNC")
    private Date                             dataCriacao;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(name = "IN_ATDT_ETN", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "br.gov.sindec.util.hibernate.tipos.SimNaoCharType")
    private Boolean                          indicadorAtendimentoEletronico;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fornecedor")
    private List<Atendimento> atendimentos;

    //more code here...
}
```

Versions of dependencies:

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-search.version>5.7.2.Final</hibernate-search.version>
<lucene.version>5.5.4</lucene.version>
```

Code to update entity (Using spring-data-jpa):

```
public void update(CadastroFornecedorPessoaJuridica cadastroFornecedorPessoaJuridica) {
    this.cadastroFornecedorPessoaJuridicaRepositorio.save(cadastroFornecedorPessoaJuridica);
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Is there another way to make it?

Comment: Does it work if you disable Envers? What's the exact code you use to update the entities? Which version of Hibernate ORM do you use? Which version of Hibernate Search?

Comment: Thks @YoannRodière. It doesn't work If Envers is disabled too. Hibernate version is 5.2.8.Final, Hibernate Search version is 5.7.2.Final. I updated my question above with the code that updates the entity.

Comment: There is a custom Field Bridge to an @EmbeddedId field -> @FieldBridge(impl = ChavePrimariaAtendimentoBridge.class). The class ChavePrimariaAtendimentoBridge implements TwoWayFieldBridge. Is the problem here?